# Oscillating System, problem with Eigenvalues and proof

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is as follows:

A number of mass/spring systems are connected together and have a mode of oscillation. All masses oscillate with frequency $\frac{n}{2\pi}$ but have different amplitudes. 'n' can be given in terms of eigenvalues $\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ = $n^2$) by the determinant:

$$ \begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda \quad -0.5 & 0 \\ -0.75\quad 1.5-\lambda & -0.75 \\ 0\quad -0.75 & 1-\lambda\\\end{vmatrix} =0 $$

Show that $16\lambda^3 -56\lambda^2 +49\lambda -9 =0 $

At a bit of a loss as I've never used Eigenvalues before. I understand matrices just don't know how to apply it correctly to show the proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Expand the determinant and see what you get. Eigenvalues are a bit of a red herring here.

Answer (score 1):

This determinant already is the equation for the eigenvalues. Apparently, there was the following matrix somewhere in the context of this question:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -0.5 & 0 \\ -0.75 & 1.5 & -0.75 \\ 0 & -0.75 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
and you needed to find its eigenvalues. Eigenvalues are determined from the **characteristic equation** $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, which is precisely what you've already set up in your question:
$$\chi(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & -0.5 & 0 \\ -0.75 & 1.5-\lambda & -0.75 \\ 0 & -0.75 & 1-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0.$$
All you've got to do now is evaluate and simplify this determinant to get the characteristic polynomial, whose roots are the eigenvalues. Expanding this determinant gives
$$\chi(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+3.5\lambda^2-3.0625\lambda+0.5625,$$
and if you multiply it by $-16$ (look at the leading coefficients), you'll get the desired result.